# OroCommerce Installation Issues on Local Mechine

Tags: npm, exception, orocommerce

I am facing an issue which is Runtime Exception 'Failed to install npm assets'. Following the below link to install oroCommerce locally for dev
https://vanderboon.net/2021/05/22/installing-orocommerce-community-4-2-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/
After this command

```
composer create-project oro/commerce-crm-application oroshop
```

it is providing some configuration options like -

```
database_driver (pdo_mysql):
database_host ('%env(ORO_DB_HOST)%'): localhost
database_port ('%env(ORO_DB_PORT)%'): 3306
database_name ('%env(ORO_DB_NAME)%'): orocomm
database_user ('%env(ORO_DB_USER)%'): orocomm
database_password ('%env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD)%'): s0m€$€cretP@$$w0rD
database_server_version ('%env(ORO_DB_VERSION)%):
database_driver_options ({ }):
mailer_transport ('%env(ORO_MAILER_DRIVER)%'):
mailer_host ('%env(ORO_MAILER_HOST)%'):
mailer_port ('%env(ORO_MAILER_PORT)%'):
mailer_encryption ('%env(ORO_MAILER_ENCRYPTION)%'):
mailer_user ('%env(ORO_MAILER_USER)%'):
mailer_password ('%env(ORO_MAILER_PASSWORD)%'):
websocket_bind_address (0.0.0.0):
websocket_bind_port (8080):
websocket_frontend_host (''): websocket_frontend_port (8080): websocket_frontend_path (''): websocket_backend_host (''):
websocket_backend_port (8080):
websocket_backend_path (''):
websocket_backend_transport (tcp):
websocket_backend_ssl_context_options ({ }):
web_backend_prefix (/admin): /admin_blurp
session_handler (session.handler.native_file):
secret ('%env(ORO_SECRET)%'):
installed (null):\n
assets_version (null):
assets_version_strategy (time_hash):
message_queue_transport (dbal):
message_queue_transport_config (null):
enable_price_sharding ('%env(bool:ORO_ENABLE_PRICE_SHARDING)%'):
deployment_type (null):
liip_imagine.jpegoptim.binary (null):
liip_imagine.pngquant.binary (null):
env(ORO_DB_HOST) (127.0.0.1):
env(ORO_DB_PORT) (null): 3306
env(ORO_DB_NAME) (b2b_crm_dev): orocomm
env(ORO_DB_USER) (root): orocomm
env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD) (null): s0m€$€cretP@$$w0rD
env(ORO_DB_VERSION) (null):
env(ORO_MAILER_DRIVER) (sendmail):
env(ORO_MAILER_HOST) (127.0.0.1):
env(ORO_MAILER_PORT) (null):
env(ORO_MAILER_ENCRYPTION) (null):
env(ORO_MAILER_USER) (null):
env(ORO_MAILER_PASSWORD) (null):
env(ORO_SECRET) (ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt):
env(ORO_ENABLE_PRICE_SHARDING) ('0'):
```

After end of the configuration exception is happening. Please look at the picture you will see the full exception.

[Failed to install npm assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkFyD.jpg)

Detail log of the exception -

```html
2001 silly tarball no local data for browserslist@4.16.7. Extracting by manifest.
2002 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/camel-case/-/camel-case-3.0.0.tgz 602ms
2003 silly tarball trying no-case@2.3.2 by hash: sha512-rmTZ9kz+f3rCvK2TD1Ue/oZlns7OGoIWP4fc3llxxRXlOkHKoWPPWJOfFYpITabSow43QJbRIoHQXtt10VldyQ==
2004 silly tarball trying resolve-cwd@2.0.0 by hash: sha1-AKn3OHVW4nA46uIyyqNypqWbZlo=
2005 silly extractTree global-prefix@3.0.0 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/global-modules/node_modules/global-prefix
2006 silly extractTree ansi-styles@3.2.1 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/ansi-styles
2007 silly extractTree escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/escape-string-regexp
2008 silly extractTree supports-color@5.5.0 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/chalk/node_modules/supports-color
2009 silly extractTree has-flag@3.0.0 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/has-flag
2010 silly extract debug@4.1.1 extracted to /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/debug (1113ms)
2011 silly extract postcss-value-parser@4.1.0 extracted to /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/postcss-modules-local-by-default/node_modules/postcss-value-parser >
2012 silly tarball trying pkg-dir@3.0.0 by hash: sha512-/E57AYkoeQ25qkxMj5PBOVgF8Kiu/h7cYS30Z5+R7WaiCCBfLq58ZI/dSeaEKb9WVJV5n/03QwrN3IeWIFllvw==
2013 silly tarball trying ansi-styles@3.2.1 by hash: sha512-VT0ZI6kZRdTh8YyJw3SMbYm/u+NqfsAxEpWO0Pf9sq8/e94WxxOpPKx9FR1FlyCtOVDNOQ+8ntlqFxiRc+r5qA==
2014 silly tarball trying escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 by hash: sha1-G2HAViGQqN/2rjuyzwIAyhMLhtQ=
2015 silly tarball trying has-flag@3.0.0 by hash: sha1-tdRU3CGZriJWmfNGfloH87lVuv0=
2016 silly extractTree ms@2.1.2 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/ms
2017 silly extract camel-case@3.0.0 extracted to /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/camel-case (818ms)
2018 silly extract js-yaml@3.13.1 extracted to /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/js-yaml (2091ms)
2019 silly extract cross-spawn@6.0.5 extracted to /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/cross-spawn (818ms)
2020 silly tarball no local data for no-case@2.3.2. Extracting by manifest.
2021 silly tarball no local data for resolve-cwd@2.0.0. Extracting by manifest.
2022 silly tarball trying global-prefix@3.0.0 by hash: sha512-awConJSVCHVGND6x3tmMaKcQvwXLhjdkmomy2W+Goaui8YPgYgXJZewhg3fWC+DlfqqQuWg8AwqjGTD2nAPVWg==
2023 silly tarball trying supports-color@5.5.0 by hash: sha512-QjVjwdXIt408MIiAqCX4oUKsgU2EqAGzs2Ppkm4aQYbjm+ZEWEcW4SfFNTr4uMNZma0ey4f5lgLrkB0aX0QMow==
2024 silly tarball trying ms@2.1.2 by hash: sha512-sGkPx+VjMtmA6MX27oA4FBFELFCZZ4S4XqeGOXCv68tT+jb3vk/RyaKWP0PTKyWtmLSM0b+adUTEvbs1PEaH2w==
2025 silly extractTree upper-case@1.1.3 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/upper-case
2026 silly extractTree argparse@1.0.10 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/argparse
2027 silly extractTree esprima@4.0.1 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/esprima
2028 silly extractTree nice-try@1.0.5 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/nice-try
2029 silly extractTree path-key@2.0.1 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/path-key
2030 silly extractTree semver@5.7.1 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/semver
2031 silly extractTree shebang-command@1.2.0 -> /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/shebang-command
2032 silly extract engine.io@3.5.0 extracted to /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/engine.io (1192ms)
2033 silly extract object.getownpropertydescriptors@2.1.2 extracted to /var/www/oroshop/node_modules/object.getownpropertydescriptors (1115ms)
2034 silly tarball no local data for pkg-dir@3.0.0. Extracting by manifest.
2035 silly tarball no local data for ansi-styles@3.2.1. Extracting by manifest.
2036 silly tarball no local data for escape-string-regexp@1.0.5. Extracting by manifest.
2037 silly tarball no local data for has-flag@3.0.0. Extracting by manifest.
2038 silly tarball trying upper-case@1.1.3 by hash: sha1-9rRQHC7EzdJrp4vnIilh3ndiFZg=
2039 silly tarball trying argparse@1.0.10 by hash: sha512-o5Roy6tNG4SL/FOkCAN6RzjiakZS25RLYFrcMttJqbdd8BWrnA+fGz57iN5Pb06pvBGvl5gQ0B48dJlslXvoTg==
```

What is the reason and solution for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the full log or the output of the `node -v` command. And you can try this workaround: https://doc.oroinc.com/bundles/platform/AssetBundle/#error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-current-environment

Comment: node version is v14.18.0. I have added the detail log along with this post